# Is it possible to extend Matt Gallagher's AudioStreamer Framework to play other formats than MP3?

Tags: iphone, audio, audiostreamer

What I need are at least these formats (or at least some of them):

- Ogg / Vorbis
- WMA over MMS/ASF
- AAC / AAC+

Matt seems to use some of the Apple frameworks for audio playback, so I wonder if it would be too hard to add support for additional formats other than only MP3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could be with FFmpeg and libmms, but I don't know how :(

Answer (score 0):

You'll be happy to know that AAC will *just work* with your audio queue.
(It does with mine).

AAC+ apparently needs some [tinkering](http://blog.stormyprods.com/2009/10/supporting-aac-via-iphone-sdk.html) to get working.

Those other formats are not supported by the SDK so obviously
no hardware love, like in the mp3/AAC[+] cases.

Answer (score -4):

Yes it is possible. No it wouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Yep, would have been nice to explain >>>HOW<<<

Comment: The question asks is it possible. I answer the question. What seems to be the problem?